# What is the maximum nose wheel deflection angle?

Tags: airliner, landing-gear, taxiing

What is the maximum nose-wheel angle of deflection on modern commercial aircraft such as the Boeing 787? Can it deflect to 90 degrees or even more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the B787, the maximum steering angle is 70°. This information can be found in the Airport Planning Manual:

> [image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/787.pdf)</sup>

For the A380, which has also a steerable main landing gear, the nose gear steering limit is the same:

> [image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/backgrounders/techdata/aircraft_characteristics/Airbus-Commercial-Aircraft-AC-A380-Dec-2016.pdf)</sup>

The center of the turn is off center, at the level of the main landing gear. With a multiple-boogie landing gear the main gear slips on the ground, which is not desirable.

This effect also occurs with a single bogie, unless the wheels are steerable. Limiting the steering angle also limits this slippage, and the wear going with it.

Comment: I suspect anything much beyond 70° would make the aircraft rather difficult to maneuver on the ground. Certainly a nose wheel fully perpendicular to the forward motion could become... interesting, if there is even the slightest thrust imbalance.

Comment: The maximums indicated here do not necessarily mean that is as far as they will go however... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBlue_Flight_292 comes to mind where Airbus A320-200 landing gear stuck at 90 degrees.